# Script for Checkboxes hidind columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 columns of checkboxes on a Sheet named "Settings". Each checkbox unchecked must hide a specific group of column of the "ROAS" Sheet.

Checkboxes locations:

### First Column of Checkboxes

- B4 : checked = show columns F, G, H on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns F, G, H
- B5 : checked = show columns I, J, K on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns I, J, K
- B6 : checked = show columns L, M, N on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns L, M, N
- B7 : checked = show columns O, P, Q on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns O, P, Q
- B8 : checked = show columns R, S, T on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns R, S, T
- B9 : checked = show columns U, V, W on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns U, V, W
- B10 : checked = show columns X, Y, Z on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns X, Y, Z
- B11 : checked = show columns AA, AB, AC on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns AA, AB, AC
- B12 : checked = show columns X, Y, Z on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns X, Y, Z
- B13 : checked = show columns AD, AE, AF on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns AD, AE, AF

### Second Column of Checkboxes

- G2 : checked = show columns B on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns B
- G3 : checked = show columns C on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns C
- G4 : checked = show columns D on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns D
- G5 : checked = show columns E on 'ROAS' / Unchecked : Hide columns E

@Tanaike here already made up this script for the first column of checkboxes, can you please help me adapt it to integrate the second column of checkboxes ?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const obj = {};
  let r = 4;
  let c = 6;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    obj[`B${r++}`] = [c, 3];
    c += 3;
  }
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var range = e.range;
  var a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  if (spreadsheet.getSheetName() == 'Settings' && Object.keys(obj).includes(a1Notation)) {
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ROAS')[range.isChecked() ? "showColumns" : "hideColumns"](...obj[a1Notation]);
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second column of checkboxes, you can add an additional for loop as well as two other variables (rTwo and cTwo in this example).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const obj = {};
  let r = 4;
  let c = 6;
  let rTwo = 2;
  let cTwo = 2;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    obj[`B${r++}`] = [c, 3];
    c += 3;
  }
  for (let j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
    obj[`G${rTwo++}`] = [cTwo, 1];
    cTwo += 1;
  }
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var range = e.range;
  var a1Notation = range.getA1Notation();
  if (spreadsheet.getSheetName() == 'Settings' && Object.keys(obj).includes(a1Notation)) {
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ROAS')[range.isChecked() ? "showColumns" : "hideColumns"](...obj[a1Notation]);
  }
}
```

The second for loop was necessary since the second column of checkboxes had a different number of columns to hide.

I have also tested the script with the setup for Settings sheet shown below:
[image]

I got ROAS sheet to show the following:
[image]